# Why do exec resources in puppet always have a previous_value of notrun?

Tags: puppet

I have a couple of Puppet `exec` resources, one of which has a `onlyif` stanza. In the reports and Puppetboard, both of them always show up as *changed*, because their `previous_value` is always `notrun`. This doesn't make any sense, especially for the one without an `onlyif` (it is run every time).

Is this a bug? What can I do to fix this?

**EDIT: Adding the code, as Ina suggested**

```
exec { 'make-plugins-executable':
  command => "/usr/bin/chmod a+x ${pluginsdir}/check*",
  require => File['plugins']
}

exec { 'nagios-permissions':
  command => "/usr/bin/chown -R nagios:nagios ${confdir}",
  onlyif  => "/usr/bin/test ! -z \"/usr/bin/find ${confdir} ! -user nagios -o ! -group nagios\""
}
```

Also, this is the output in the log:

```
2018-07-23 11:40:48 +0100 /Stage[main]/Bcc_nagios/Exec[make-plugins-executable]/returns (notice): executed successfully
2018-07-23 11:40:48 +0100 /Stage[main]/Bcc_nagios::Master/Exec[nagios-permissions]/returns (notice): executed successfully
2018-07-23 11:40:58 +0100 Puppet (notice): Applied catalog in 10.09 seconds
```

They get run, but they show up as `notrun` in `last_run_summary.yaml`

Comment: Can you post your exec code here? It would help if we had a specific example to look at.

Comment: @InaTsetsova Thanks for your response. I have also added the log output, to show that they are run.

Comment: why not use a the file type

Comment: @balder Thanks for the suggestion. I didn't know I could use the `file` resource like that. I will try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write that it does not make any sense to you that the following `Exec` is always reported as changed, apparently because you expect the `onlyif` to prevent that:

> ```
> exec { 'nagios-permissions':
>   command => "/usr/bin/chown -R nagios:nagios ${confdir}",
>   onlyif  => "/usr/bin/test ! -z \"/usr/bin/find ${confdir} ! -user nagios -o ! -group nagios\""
> }
> ```

But it *does* make sense.  The command you have given in `onlyif` does not do what you seem to think it does.  Here is how it appears without the Puppet-level quoting and escaping:

```
/usr/bin/test ! -z "/usr/bin/find /some/directory ! -user nagios -o ! -group nagios"
```

That command will always return 0 (true): it just tests whether the given string is nonempty.  No `find` command is run; the test just passes by examination of the argument.  As a result, the `chown` in the main `command` always is run, and that is reported.

You appear to want something more like this:

```
exec { 'nagios-permissions':
  command => "/usr/bin/chown -R nagios:nagios ${confdir}",
  onlyif  => "/bin/sh -c \"'!' -z `/usr/bin/find /some/directory '!' -user nagios -o '!' -group nagios`\""
}
```

Note the three different kinds of quotes (four if you include `\` escaping).  Note, too, that you need to be sure the shell is invoked to run the command, as shown, because it relies on a command substitution.

As was suggested in comments on the question, however, it is probably better to use a recursive `File` resource for this sort of job than to handle it via an `Exec`.  I would expect that to report changes only when one or more files actually have their properties changed.